# How can I react when a user touches an HTML element on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, ios

I'm displaying some HTML content in my iPhone app using a UIWebView.  I have an image link, and I want it to change when the user touches it - at the moment the user puts a finger on the screen, rather than waiting until they lift their finger back off.

What CSS or JavaScript concept could accomplish this?  I've looked at the `hover` and `active` states in CSS, but they don't seem to be what I'm after: `hover` relates to touch-up rather than touch-down, while `active` seems to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this.

I think it should be what you are looking for!

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/iphone-development-12-tips/2

> 8: Touch Events
>
> Of course, you use your iPhone with a
>   finger instead of a mouse; rather than
>   clicking, you tap. What’s more, you
>   can use several fingers to touch and
>   tap. On the iPhone, mouse events are
>   replaced by touch events. They are:
>
> - `touchstart`
> - `touchend`
> - `touchmove`
> - `touchcancel` (when the system cancels the touch)
>
> When you subscribe to any of those
>   events, your event listener will
>   receive an event object. The event
>   object has some important properties,
>   such as:
>
> - `touches` — a collection of touch objects, one for each finger that
>     touches the screen. The touch objects
>     have, for example, pageX and pageY
>     properties containing the coordinates
>     of the touch within the page.
> - `targetTouches` — works like touches, but only registers touches on
>     a target element as opposed to the
>     whole page.
>
> The next example is a simple
>   implementation of drag and drop. Let’s
>   put a box on a blank page and drag it
>   around. All you need to do is
>   subscribe to the touchmove event and
>   update the position of the box as the
>   finger moves around, like so:
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('load', function() {
>     var b = document.getElementById('box'),  
>         xbox = b.offsetWidth  / 2, // half the box width  
>         ybox = b.offsetHeight / 2, // half the box height  
>         bstyle = b.style; // cached access to the style object  
>     b.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {     
>         event.preventDefault(); // the default behaviour is scrolling     
>         bstyle.left = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - xbox + 'px';
>         bstyle.top  = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - ybox + 'px';
>     }, false);  
> }, false);
> ```
>
> The `touchmove` event listener first cancels the default behavior of the finger move—otherwise Safari will scroll the page. The collection `event.targetTouches` contains a list of data for each finger currently on the target div element.
>   We only care about one finger, so we use `event.targetTouches[0]`. Then `pageX` gives us the X coordinate of the finger. From this value we subtract half the width of the div so that the finger stays in the center of the box.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try the Javascript "onMouseDown", hopefully the mobile Safari will fire the event.

```
<a href="#any_URL" onMouseDown="callSomeFunction();return true;">Link</a>
```

Comment: From http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html: "The iPhone fires the mousedown, mouseup and click events in the correct order on a click (tap), but it either fires all three or none at all. Holding your finger down on an element and waiting for it to lose focus after a while does not fire any events, even though a case could be made for firing the mousedown event as soon as the user’s finger touches the screen."

Comment: @idealmachine - shame :( Thanks for finding that source though.